# VBA split full file name into columns (directory, folder, folder, filename, extension, etc.)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Cannot find answer from google on this.  Trying to write a VBA excel macro that splits the full file name into multiples columns based on slash "\"... Example:  In one particular folder, I have 100 files.  Would like to split these 100 filenames into:

```
     Filename:  C:\Users\Public\Finance\Reports\BalanceSheet.xls
```

column A: Z:\Users\Public\Finance\Reports\BalanceSheet.xls

column B: Z:

column C:  Users

column D:  Public

column E:  Finance

column F:  Reports

column G:  BalanceSheet.xls

column H:  xls

Of course do this for all the files in the folder (100 files currently).  I know columns A-F are repeating, but please indulge me.

Thank you!!

Comment: You probably want to look at [SPLIT](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) in Excel and perhaps this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414106/get-list-of-excel-files-in-a-folder-using-vba).

Comment: Thank you so much Anak!!   Using the links you provided, here are my final codes above.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to assist. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new Module (common, not class!). Insert the below code into it:

```
Public Function GetComponent(str As String, delim As String, num As Integer) As String
Dim tmp() As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
tmp = Split(str, delim)
Select Case num
    Case 0 To UBound(tmp)
        GetComponent = tmp(num)
    Case UBound(tmp) + 1
        GetComponent = Split(tmp(num - 1), ".")(1)
    Case Else
        GetComponent = ""
    End Select
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
GetComponent = ""
End Function
```

Now this function is available in formula builder in User-Defined Functions section.

If source data is in A1, then put the formula (using formula builder or "by hands")

```
=GetComponent($A1,"\",COLUMN()-2)
```

into B1 cell, then grad it horizontally far enough to display all filename components.

Comment: Akina - Wow... I have never created a function before, and this is perfect!!  Thank you sir!!

Comment: Hi Akina!!  Works perfect.... Quick follow-up... How do I change this to display by row (instead of by column)...?

Comment: Hi... I figured it now, thank you again!!  

=GetComponent(A$1,"\",ROW()-2)

Answer (score 1):

Split `filename`, loop through each part to set the cells' values.

```
Public Sub SplitName()

Dim filename As String

filename = "C:\Users\Public\Finance\Reports\BalanceSheet.xls"
Dim columnsname() As String

columnsname = Split(filename, "\")

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = filename 'Set value for Column A

Dim count As Integer
count = 2 'Column counter: will start with Column B

For Each part In columnsname

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, count).Value = part
count = count + 1

Next

columnsname = Split(filename, ".")
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, count).Value = columnsname(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I got it now... I should add comment here.  Thank you again, Reddy!!  I see you answer alot of VBA questions, wow... an expert!!  I hope to get there one day!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub File_SplitName()

     Dim fileName_Full As String
     Dim fileName_Component() As String

     fileName_Full = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
     fileName_Component = Split(fileName_Full, "\")

     On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("B").Range("AI61").Value = fileName_Full
    Sheets("B").Range("AI62").Value = fileName_Component(0)
    Sheets("B").Range("AI63").Value = fileName_Component(1)
    Sheets("B").Range("AI64").Value = fileName_Component(2)
    Sheets("B").Range("AI65").Value = fileName_Component(3)
    Sheets("B").Range("AI66").Value = fileName_Component(4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Reddy - That is very succinct and creative, makes the code shorter, thank you very much!!  Will use this one.

Comment: You commented to yourself even though it was directed at me :)

Comment: Add the code for the last column for the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Another method:  Just use the text-to-columns method:

```
Option Explicit
Sub pathSplitter()
    Dim rPaths As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

'Declare worksheet and range to split
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2") 'adjust as needed

With ws 'assumes range starts in A1.  Adjust if that is not the case
    Set rPaths = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1))
End With

'set all the arguments so as to avoid any interference from previous usages
rPaths.TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, 2), DataType:=xlDelimited, textqualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
     consecutivedelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=False, _
     other:=True, otherchar:="\"

ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```